# Cannot activate Windows 10 Enterprise E3

Tags: windows-10, office365, windows-activation, licensing

I bought a windows 10 enterprise E3 license.

I have logged in with my admin @mydomain.onmicossoft.com account, created a new user and assigned the license to it.

I then logged in with that user and tried to download an iso or something similar to install windows. Cannot find any place to do that.

I went to a public microsoft url where you can download a media creation iso and burn it into a usb pen. I selected windows 10 pro, and ran the installer.

It asks me for a serial, which I don't have and I choose the option to proceed without serial key.

After the installation, I try activating the windows and I can't. I try creating a new user account with the email associated with the license, but I get an error message saying the user is not valid. I can login through the browser with that account and see the license in my user area, but I see no place to activate the installation.

Where can I download a iso for installing E3 correctly? How should I do this?

**UPDATE**

1 - I have tried configuring windows with a local user, and also for work with the same user that has the license assigned to it. None of these options results in an activated windows installation.

2 - I have tried two different installation media. One of them allows me to choose the windows version before creating the bootable media, while the other creates the bootable media and only inside windows installation will I choose to go with home or pro editions. In none of these versions is an option to choose enterprise, as suggested in one of the comments.

Comment: You "bought... [E]nterprise" license. You tried to install "10 [P]ro". See https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: I should install the iso from that link is that it? I don't see anywhere to choose the version, I just download the iso and choose when installing? @DrMois

Comment: Follow the directions on that page.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I am done this again, but that is exactly the same process I used before and mentioned in this post. I download the media creation tool (in another pc), created a bootable usb disk with Windows 10. When I install, it asks me which version to use (there is no enterprise, just home and pro). I choose pro, proceed without serial key and when it finishes the setup, I find no way of adding my existing license key to the installation.

Comment: You have to use the Volume License website, to download an appropriate Windows 10 Enterprise ISO, as you have found the Media Creation Tool doesn’t download the appropriate ISO

Comment: @Ramhound I am not sure what credentials to use to access the Volume License website. I have tried both my admin@...onmicrosoft.com and the other account to which I associated the license, but I can't login with either of them.

Answer (score 0):

As you brought a enterprise volume activation key, so we should download enterprise ISO image and activate enterprise system with this key. So please go to https://www.microsoft.com/Licensing/servicecenter/default.aspx to download enterprise ISO. After you installed OS, and can't find activation, we could run "slui.exe 4" to acticate through Phone call.

Comment: can this slui.exe and phone activation be done over the pro version?

Comment: yeah, it also apply on Windows 10 Professional version for system activation.